# Обойти блокировку IO

Tags: java, android

Выполняю `HttpsUrlConnection` подключение в метода `shouldInterceptRequest` в классе `WebViewClient`. Но как [вычитал](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65786) в версии Android 4.4 там происходит блокировка IO. Как её можно обойти? А то выполнение `HttpsUrlConnection` прерывается сразу же как только я пытаюсь получить `InputStream`. Причем если просто выполнить этот запрос при помощи `new Thread(new Runnable(){...}).start();` все прекрасно сработает.

```
@Override
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
    try {
        HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = getHttpsConnection(url, false);
        Log.d("logba", "A -> getData : status=" + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
        InputStream stream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        Log.d("logba", "A -> getData : stream=" + stream);
        return new WebResourceResponse("text/html", "utf-8", stream);
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
    }
    return null;
}

private HttpsURLConnection getHttpsConnection(String url, boolean isPost) throws IOException {
    URL urlConnection = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection httpsURLConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
    //httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
    httpsURLConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
    httpsURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    httpsURLConnection.setDoOutput(isPost);
    httpsURLConnection.setUseCaches(true);
    httpsURLConnection.setReadTimeout(60_000);
    httpsURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60_000);
    httpsURLConnection.setRequestMethod(isPost ? POST : GET);
    return httpsURLConnection;
}
```

Comment: Так может и работать в отдельном потоке? Почему нет?

Comment: обвернуть HttpsUrlConnection в new Thread(...) не сложно, а как вернуть WebResourceResponse?

Comment: Через Callable. https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html

Comment: Вот пример http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002080/android-callable

Comment: Статья с примером: http://prologistic.com.ua/java-callable-kratkoe-opisanie-i-primer-ispol-zovaniya.html